# adding unique class for new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want add a unique class for each new div after input, how is it in my code?

Add class for this: `<div class="thing"></div>`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/2/ => please in here(field) typing a number for adding new input.

```
function unique() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

$('input').live("keyup", function () {
    $('.lee').empty();
    var $val = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < $val; i++) {
        $('.lee').append('<input type="text" name="hi" class="">div class="thing"></div>');
        $('input[hi]').next('div').attr('class', unique())
    }
});
```

Comment: if it will be unique why not use id attribute.. also unique returns a random class not a unique class..

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what possible use it could be to assign a different random class to each DIV. Classes are meant to group similar elements; uniqueness is the province of IDs.

Comment: Wait, why are you adding a unique class in the first place ?

Comment: I can see why you would want to.  (not in this case but still...)  When you are already using an id, a unique class can serve as another id without overriding your old one.

Comment: i really don't get what you are trying to accomplish.. however... .length in i < $val is missing

Comment: My question is not about the word unique. Please tell me about add new class (output `unique()`) Instead of class `.thing` on `<div class="thing"></div>` in each new input.

Comment: How can make a word unique with 5 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var increment = 0;

function unique() {
    return "u" + increment++;
}
```

can't that work?

Comment: My question is not about the word unique. Please tell me about add new class (output `unique()`) Instead of class `.thing` on `<div class="thing"></div>` in each new input.

Comment: @Jennifer Anthony Well, you could just do `$('.lee').append('<input type="text" name="hi" class=""><div class="'+unique()+'"></div>');`

Comment: @Jennifer Anthony `return ("u" + (1000 + increment++));`  for up to 9000 unique values.

Comment: I don't want is word behind(orderly) like: `u1000` => `u1001` => `u1002` => ... . i want mix of word and number like: `s4a5d` => `jd5s4` => `54s6a` => ... . how is it?